# Show directly that $x_n = {n+1 \over n}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta, cauchy-sequences

I started out my proof by stating that for $\epsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N(\epsilon/2)$ such that 
$$\text{if $n,m > N(\epsilon/2)$ then $|x_m - x_n| < \epsilon$.}$$
Then I worked it out until I ended up with ${1 \over m} + {1 \over n}\le {\epsilon \over 2} + {\epsilon \over 2} = \epsilon$. My teacher wrote back that I needed to use the Archimedean Property because "Cauchyness" can't be assumed and I'm confused on what I need to do.

Comment: "$N(\epsilon) = \epsilon/2$ such that if $n,m > N(\epsilon/2)$" ?! What does this mean / what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I think he just got confused there, and meant $n,m>N$ or $n,m > \frac \epsilon 2$.

Comment: Here's the definition of cauchy that I have: A sequence $x_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence if |$x_m$ - $x_n$| conv. to zero as n,m > $\infty$ ; iff for all $\epsilon$ > 0, there is N($\epsilon$) in the Natural Numbers such that if m>n>N($\epsilon$), then |$x_m$ - $x_n$| < $\epsilon$.

Comment: Yep, YoTengo got it. It's just the preference of my teacher & textbook to write it that way.

Comment: We have $|x_n - x_m| = |1/n - 1/m|$ and we can use the triangle inequality to get $|x_n - x_m| \leq 1/n + 1/m$. Now we need to show that this can be as small as possible when $n,m$ is large enough. Given $\epsilon >0$, then by the Archimedean propery there exist a $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now if $n,m>N$ then $1/n + 1/m < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\frac1n+\frac1m=\varepsilon
$$
is likely to fail for most choices of $\varepsilon$, since the left-hand-side is rational.

As your teacher says, you cannot assume that your sequence is Cauchy. Here is one way to argue. You have
$$
\left|x_m-x_n\right|=\left|\frac{m+1}m-\frac{n+1}n\right|=\left|\frac1m-\frac1n\right|\leq\frac1{\min\{m,n\}}.
$$
The last step assures us that we can deal with each of $m,n$ at a time. We want the right-hand-side to be less than $\varepsilon$. This implies that we need both $m,n>1/\varepsilon$.

So if you take $N(\varepsilon)$ be an integer greater than $1/\varepsilon$, then whenever $m,n>N(\varepsilon)$ you'll have that $|x_m-x_n|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: What does it mean to "assume the sequence is Cauchy?"

Comment: When you say "I started my proof by stating that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon/2$ such that if $n,m>N(\varepsilon/2)$ then $|x_m-x_n|<\varepsilon$. The whole point of the proof you are expected to make is to show that such $N$ exists. And it won't be equal to $\varepsilon/2$, which you want to be small.